# How do I change the width of the hr Element, if the input is focused but in an other span?

Tags: html, css, telerik

I am using **Telerik** to generate a textbox. Now I would like to equip this with an animation.

The problem is that Telerik wraps a **span** around the input, so I don't know how to change the **hr** element when the input is focused.

My Code:

```css
span.inputanimation {
    width: 100%;
}

// Here is what i dont know how to do !
span.inputanimation > .input > input:focus hr.underline {
    width: 100%;
}

hr.underline {
    width: 0%;
    transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #17e13f;
    height: 2px;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 2px;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Generated with TelerikTextBox -->
<span class="inputanimation">
  <span class="input">
    <input id="Vorname">
</span>
<hr class="underline">
</span>

</body>
</html>
```

I removed some of the CSS classes and HTML Properties so it is better to look at.

My Telerik Code:

```
<span class="inputanimation">
        <TelerikTextBox @bind-Value="Value"
                        Id="@Id"
                        PlaceHolder="@Label"
                        Class="input">
        </TelerikTextBox>
        <hr class="underline" >

    </span>
```

Comment: Because **hr** is inside a **span**, it will go from the input to the end of line.  Is that what you are intending ?

Comment: My css is not that hot, but I think this is closer to what you want.  **span.inputanimation input:focus ~ hr.underline {
    width: 100%;
}**

Comment: Close. Because it is in an other span I need something like this: span.inputanimation > span.input > input:focus < hr.underline {width 100%}. But this does not work.

Comment: I think you are making it too complicated.

Comment: Yes I know but I just don't get it. Do you know how it can work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at various posts on hover and focus, it seems that the two elements have to be related, such as child or sibling.  Which would be easy if you weren't using **Telerik**.

### One solution is  to use **javascript**. I am using ids to show the concept.

```js
let search = document.getElementById('Vorname');
let ruler = document.getElementById('Ruler');

search.onfocus = function(){ ruler.style.width = '100%'; }
```

```css
span.inputanimation {
    width: 100%;
}


hr.underline {
    width: 0%;
    transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #17e13f;
    height: 2px;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 2px;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Generated with TelerikTextBox -->
<span class="inputanimation">
  <span class="input">
    <input id="Vorname">
</span>
<hr id="Ruler" class="underline">
</span>

</body>
</html>
```

### Another solution is to use **focus-within**

```css
span.inputanimation {
    width: 100%;
}

span.inputanimation:focus-within hr.underline {
    width: 100%;;
}

hr.underline {
    width: 10%;
    transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #17e13f;
    height: 2px;
    border: none;
  margin-top: 2px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Generated with TelerikTextBox -->
<span class="inputanimation">
  <span class="input">
    <input id="Vorname">
 </span>
   <hr id='Ruler' class="underline">
</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. What about focus-within could that work without JS?

Comment: Dont forget to upvote. I will have a look tomorrow. If the aim is to underline it. there could be other ways.

Comment: Yes it is the aim. But since i use blazor I don’t want JS. If it is possible to do it only with CSS the code would be much easier. Thank you for your help.